# Do Australia and New Zealand have a travel ban on Somalis (like Wikipedia says)?

Tags: visas, australia, new-zealand, somali-citizens

The Wikipedia article on [visa requirements for Somali Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Somali_citizens) lists three countries that refuse admission to Somali citizens: the US, Australia & New Zealand.

I know the US travel ban is true—it was all over the news— but I had never heard of Australia and NZ having  a travel ban for Somalis? Is this actually true, or is this a classic case of Wikipedia being a less than reliable source?

Comment: Note that as far as Somalia is concerned, the US travel ban is only strictly a ban for immigrant visas;  non-immigrant visas can still be granted in principle, but they're subjected to higher scrutiny.  See [Section 2(h)(ii) of Presidential Proclamation 9645.](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/presidential-proclamation-enhancing-vetting-capabilities-processes-detecting-attempted-entry-united-states-terrorists-public-safety-threats/)  Of course, this additional scrutiny may make it very difficult for a Somali national to obtain a visa at all.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert there are of course several exceptions in the proclamation as well.

Comment: So people are not surprised, I edited Wikipedia to reflect the answers here.

Comment: News to me, as a NZer. | Interest only: I have been told I couldn't LEAVE NZ without a return air ticket if I was leaving on a short trip. I wanted to leave the return leg open as I did not know how I would use my tourist-run-around-and-take-photos- return trip after a business trip to China. I was however told that ANY valid incoming ticket to NZ would be acceptable and could have booked eg an open changeable date ticket from "across the pond" / Oz for $100-$200 and left it open and used i indefinitely. That **MAY** have SOME relevance to an outgoing Somali air ticket too.

Comment: @DJClayworth Someone reverted your Wikipeida edits, citing Timatic.  Apparently Timatic is saying Somali citizens are not permitted to enter Australia or New Zealand, even though there is no law from either country prohibiting entry by Somali citizens

Comment: @k2moo4:  I suppose that if Timatic says that there's a ban, it's functionally equivalent to there actually being a ban.  The airlines are probably going to go by what it says, even if it's wrong.

Answer (score 16):

The Wikipedia article conflicts with information available directly from the New Zealand government.

Following the links on the NZ government visa page [here](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/visit) allows one to enter "Somalia" for country of passport, and returns [a screen](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/visit/explore-visitor-visa-options) showing that a Visitor Visa is available and requires these things:

- You must show that you’re a genuine tourist or visitor and intend to leave New Zealand at the end of your stay.
- You must have enough money to live on while you’re in New Zealand or have an acceptable sponsor.
- You must have a ticket to leave New Zealand or be sponsored for the cost of your onward travel.

Answer (score 9):

Further to the answer for New Zealand, the article also appears to be incorrect regarding Australia. The [Australian government's visa options website](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/visit) also allows selection of Somalia as country of passport, and presents visa options for tourism or business travel.

Answer (score 3):

The closest law that I can find to banning Somalians from New Zealand is [United Nations Sanctions (Somalia) Regulations 2018](http://legislation.govt.nz/regulation/public/2018/0068/latest/LMS39522.html?src=qs), which only applies to designated people on a UN list.
No Somali passport is allowed to be endorsed [however](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/opsmanual/#46160.htm), which mean you have to get a Certificate of Identity to travel to New Zealand.